# Why the transitions do not work in my case

Tags: wordpress, background, hover, css-transitions

I'd like to know why my transition doesn't work in **Wordpress** while in Codepen it works fine. Hovering on items changes background but it also should do with **transition**

I am mentally exhausted trying to find out if it's just my stupid mistake or something else in Wordpress could block it.

```
Here is my codepen
```

: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Contemplator191/pen/qBmXgjP)

`Here is the website I'm applying it to:` [Wordpress page](https://harton.weboktoromniktonevie.sk/index.php/uvod/)

Answer (score 1):

change the transition from background to background-image

`background-image 350ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1)`

```
.container #picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #f5bf30;
    transition: background-image 350ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
```

Source: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Edit 1:

Initial background using 1x1px image

```
.container #picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8ut/gPwAHegLlBdE8JgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    transition: background-image 350ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
```

the image used in this example is generated with [png-pixel](https://png-pixel.com/)

Edit 2:

I had a look at your implementation of my suggested change,

you want to replace `transition: background 1350ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) !important;` with `transition: background-image 350ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);` for the initial setup `.container #picture`

it works perfect like that when I test it.

and remove the rules you added to `.container #picture.one`, `.container #picture.two`, ... etc

[image]

Edit 3:

Side by side example showing the difference between color to image and image to image transition;

```css
.square {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  transition: background-image 350ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  float: left;
  margin-right:50px;
}
.example-1 {
  background: #f5bf30;
}

.example-2 {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8ut/gPwAHegLlBdE8JgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
.example-1:hover, .example-2:hover{
 background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
}
```

```html
<div class="square example-1"></div>
<div class="square example-2"></div>
```

Comment: Well, that's a good point but it doesn't work somehow. I changed background to background image and also did that with transition. I don't understand why...

Comment: @MarekCmarko you can replace the initial background color with a 1px wide img in that color or replace it with a base64 hash. i added this to the solution

Comment: Hi @Jasper B,   

I removed transitions from concrete items and left it only for .container #picture.
Though I don't fully understand technique with 1x1 px image but i tried it, and it has no effect when I reload it... How is that possible - can you see it here working ? 

https://harton.weboktoromniktonevie.sk/uvod/

Comment: the pixel image is to allow smooth transition from a static color to an image. As you cant transition like this from a background color to an image this little hack will replace the color with a image of the same color. Your implementation still seems a bit jerky trough (if you transition between multiple links fast) likely due to 2 transitions types (eg background and background-image) conflicting with each other. all the css you need for the transition is the css in the first edit

Comment: I added a example showing you the diffrence between using the pixel and the color background

Comment: I believe i theoretically understand it, tried it also in codepen and so, but I'm not able to set the transition on the page I mentioned earlier in comment. I really do not know how to use it there, 'am confused combining it...still not working
Could you try , if it's just about my stupidity ?...